# ¿Por qué me sale este mensaje de error? Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function session_star() in

Tags: php

He visto que dicen que es porque el en el PHP esta función de sesiones puede estar desactivada, pero les juro que en la mía esta activada, otra cosa es que debe estar al principio del código y también lo esta, ya no se que mas hacer ahí les dejo mi código que es simple y eso q solo estoy probando para hacer algo mas complejo y no me sale ni así:

```
<?php 
        session_star();
        $_SESSION['variable']='hola';
        ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="prueba.php">Ir a prueba</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Eso me debe llevar a otra página y mostrar una variable pero ni esta primera página me sale.

Comment: Tienes un error tipográfico, es `session_start()` y no `session_star()`.

Comment: Te he arreglado la pregunta. Debes marcar el texto y luego el botón de código (el que tiene los corchetes `{}`) para que te muestre el código. No me he dado cuenta que habías puesto código hasta que quise corregir tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ¿Por qué me sale este mensaje de error?

El mensaje de error te explica el motivo por el que sale:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function session_star() in ...

- **Fatal error**: se trata de un **error fatal** que detendrá la ejecución de tu script.
- **Uncaught Error**: es un error no capturado por ningún método cuya descripción es la siguiente:
- **Call to undefined function session_star() in**: o *llamada a la función no definida `session_star()`*.

De modo que el error te sale porque no has capturado un error llamando a una función inexistente, `session_star()`, debido a que la que deseas llamar se llama realmente [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start).

Comment: No me gusta responder a una pregunta que debería ser cerrada, pero ya que han publicado y  puntuado +1 otra respuesta, al menos voy a responder a su pregunta correctamente.

Comment: tenlo por seguro que tendré mas preguntas ya que estoy en un proyecto de tesis y le daré las mejores puntuaciones por su ayuda :)

Answer (score 2):

es `session_start()` no `session_star`

Comment: Esto es más bien un comentario y no una respuesta ya que se trata de un error tipográfico y la pregunta debe cerrarse por dicho motivo.

Comment: dios mio no puedo creer que haya caido en un error tan tonto muchas gracias amigo

Comment: De nada :) un placer ayudar.

Comment: eso me pasa por copiar codigos de internet jajaja